# Disable state in URL in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Shiny 0.14 has introduced [bookmarkable state](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) and a GET parameter that encodes the current state seems to be included in the URL by default.

Unfortunately the state of my app isn't easily saved and copy&pasting the URL with the state parameter to another browser session crashes the app immediately. Removing the GET parameter from the URL initializes the app in its default state, which works just fine.

So, is there any way to disable the state GET parameter? Calling `enableBookmarking("disable")` before calling `shinyServer()` doesn't seem to do the trick. This is true both when I run the app from within RStudio and in deployment using shiny-server.

According to the [manual](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) "For applications that use ui.R and server.R, there should also be a global.R with a call to enableBookmarking()" but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: maybe try to argument to `shinyApp`... `shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "disable")`

Comment: I use the setup with separate `ui.R`, `server.R` and `global.R` files, in which case I initialize the app by calling `shinyServer()` in `server.R`.

Comment: Could you please include a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I can't reproduce. When I have `enableBookmarking(store = "disable")` in global.R, nothing happens when I click on bookmark button

Comment: Going to be very hard to help in your specific case if you don't provide an example